# VirtualBox on mac osx with NAT networks hangs OSX

Tags: osx, virtualbox

I am trying run virtualbox machine with newly created NAT Network.
Network CIDR 10.0.2.0/24
Checked Supports DHCP
If I choose for virtual machine this network than OSX hangs, and restarts..
Here are logs:

- https://pastebin.com/sBXFhrvX
- https://pastebin.com/bXzkcYft
- https://pastebin.com/54MHxYHV
- https://pastebin.com/in1HVmXB

version of vbox is 6.0.8

Comment: I have a similar issue. And there are others with the same issue as well (https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14748, https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=86753). Have you found a solution?